# can't delete a string from a list

Tags: python

I wrote the following code:

```
f = copy.deepcopy(features)
if best_att in features:
   f = features.remove(best_att)
```

where `features` is a list of strings and `best_att` is a string. Sometimes the code works fine, but sometimes I get the following problem:

If, for example, `features = ['outlook', 'temperature', 'humidity', 'wind']`, and `best_att = 'outlook'`. When debugging, I see that it enters the `if`. However, when trying to preform the `remove`, it gets an error: `f` is `NoneType: None` (i.e., it couldn't find the string in the list).

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: `list.remove()` doesn't return anything, you shouldn't be storing it into the variable `f`. Just do `f.remove(best_att)` if you wanna remove the `best_att` from `f`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
f = copy.deepcopy(features)
if best_att in f:
    f.remove(best_att)
```

or

```
if best_att in features:
    features.remove(best_att)
```

It seems from your code that you want to change the original `features`, so just do that. If you want also want a deepcopy `f` of it, create that after modifying `features`.

You got that message because `remove` returns `None`: after you assign its return value to `f`, that's the value of `f` too. In general, Python builtin methods that mutate state "don't return anything" (they return `None`) -- they're "all side-effect". The return value is **not** the mutated object, and it is **not** a success/failure flag. Some languages draw the distinction between "procedures" and "functions"; these would be "procedures".

If you want to know whether, say, `best_att` is in `features`, use `features.find(best_att)` or `features.index(best_att)`.

Answer (score 2):

`L.remove` returns `None`, which is then assigned to the original list.
 `help([].remove)` is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

In python, lists are mutable, which you are probably aware of, since you are using `deepcopy`

If you call `list.remove` on `f`, it changes `f` and returns `None`

```
>>> f = ["spam", "eggs", "harald"]
>>> print(f.remove("harald"))
None
>>> print(f)
["spam", "eggs"]
```